# Как правильно написать запрос с group by?

Tags: sql

Добрый день!
Основываясь на [данном примере](http://2sql.ru/novosti/sql-group-by/), как правильно написать запрос , чтобы в результате получился ответ вида

```
Singer          LastAlbumYear    Sale
Drowning Pool   2013             500000
Massive Attack  2004             1900000
The Prodigy     2008             1200000
```

То есть: Название группы, дата выхода последнего альбома, количество продаж  последнего альбома

```
SELECT Singer, MAX(Year) AS LastAlbumYear, sale
FROM Artists
GROUP BY Singer, sale;
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Если в запрос добавить колонку `sale`, то она обязательно должна быть в `GROUP BY` и соответственно кол-во строк в ответе увеличивается. Как получить нужный мне ответ?

Comment: все зависит от того какую сумму вам нужно получить

Comment: Зачем вам group by, если вы не хотите ничего группировать?

Comment: Группирую по группам. Или логика запроса не верна ?

Comment: Решение для какой СУБД интересует? В оракле есть конструкция с `KEEP`, в постгресе есть похожая, они позволяют сделать это в "один заход", без подзапросов. Про другие СУБД не знаю. Без этого - только с подзапросами, как Anton Shchyrov написал ниже.

Comment: @Dmitry , интересует postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно, такое решается подзапросом с джойном основной таблицы

```
SELECT
  sub.Singer,
  sub.LastAlbumYear,
  art.sale
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Singer, MAX(Year) AS LastAlbumYear
    FROM
      Artists
    GROUP BY
      Singer
  ) sub
  LEFT JOIN Artists art ON (
    art.Singer = sub.Singer
    art.Year = sub.LastAlbumYear
  )
```

Comment: Спасибо. в конце добавил еще GROUP BY sub.Singer, sub.LastAlbumYear, art.sale и получил то, что хотел. А возможно данную задачe решbть без подзапросов ?

Comment: @Adrenal1ne Если мой ответ помог Вам, отметьте его как правильный. P.S. А зачем Вам второй GROUP BY? Чтоб было?

Comment: Ваш ответ безусловно помог. Поясню про group by. Делаю запрос как у вас , получаю ответ https://hkar.ru/Rh4a . Добавляю group by и получаю нужный результат https://hkar.ru/Rh4b . Может я чего-то не допонял ?

Comment: @Adrenal1ne Не может такого быть. Только если у Вас в БД дублируются записи. Сделайте выборку `SELECT * FROM Artists WHERE Singer = 'The Prodigy' AND year = 2008` и посмотрите, что получится. Сколько записей выберет?

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы, дублируются. Сразу видно, что человек знает о чем говорит. Еще раз спасибо за правильный ответ  и извините за недопонимание темы.

Comment: Просто интересно, раз записи дублируются, то вы использовали MIN(art.sale) или MAX(art.sale)?

Comment: @МаксимСеливановских А зачем? `GROUP BY` по всем полям эквивалентен `DISTINCT`

Comment: @Максим Селивановских  если вопрос ко мне, то в комментарии (3-ий сверху) есть примеры моих запросов в скриншотах.

Comment: Увидел, думал дубли с разными ценами. Дубли оказывается полные. Лучше от них избавиться (они не несут никакой пользы), и убрать лишний GROUP BY - оптимизация.